# Consulta SQL con 4 tablas relacionadas

Tags: sql

Estoy aprendiendo SQL para hacer consultas y todavía no entiendo muy bien cómo hacerlas con tablas que estan relacionadas.

Mis 4 tablas son las siguientes...

Primera tabla:

```
create table empleado (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1),
    nombreempleado varchar(255),
    calle varchar(255),
    ciudad varchar(255),

    -- Create Clustered
     CONSTRAINT pk_empleado PRIMARY KEY clustered (id)
     )
```

Segunda tabla:

```
create table empresa (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1),
    nombreempresa varchar(255),
    ciudad varchar(255),

    CONSTRAINT pk_empresa PRIMARY KEY clustered (id),
    )
```

Tercera tabla:

```
create table jefe (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1),
    id_empresa int,
    nombrejefe varchar(255),
    calle varchar(255),
    ciudad varchar(255),

    CONSTRAINT pk_jefe PRIMARY KEY clustered (id),

    -- Create a Foreign Key
    CONSTRAINT fk_jefe_empresa FOREIGN KEY (id_empresa) REFERENCES empresa (id)
    )
```

Cuarta tabla:

```
create table trabaja (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1),
    id_empleado int,
    id_empresa int,
    sueldo money,

    CONSTRAINT pk_trabaja PRIMARY KEY clustered (id),

    CONSTRAINT fk_trabaja_empleado FOREIGN KEY (id_empleado) REFERENCES empleado (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_trabaja_empresa FOREIGN KEY (id_empresa) REFERENCES empresa (id)
    )
```

Hasta ahora, las consultas sencillas me han salido correctamente, el problema viene cuando tengo que hacer esto:

> Buscar todos los empleados que viven en la misma ciudad y en la misma
>   calle que sus jefes.

El código que tengo hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
SELECT nombreempleado
    FROM empleado
    INNER JOIN trabaja ON trabaja.id_empleado = empleado.id
    INNER JOIN trabaja ON trabaja.id_empresa = empresa.id
    WHERE
```

Qué condición tengo que poner?
Estoy enlazando correctamente los ID?

Cualquier ayuda sería bienvenida, saludos a todos y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Saludos**

Por lo que observo mi sugerencia es:

```
SELECT nombreempleado, nombrejefe
FROM empleado emp
INNER JOIN TRABAJA TRB ON TRB.id_empleado=EMP.id
INNER JOIN jefe  JEF ON JEF.calle=EMP.calle AND JEF.ciudad=EMP.ciudad  
                 /* misma calle y ciudad */
               AND JEF.id_empresa=TRB.id_empresa 
                /* Misma empresa */
```

Prueba lo anterior; solo que considerar que calle y ciudad al ser datosde texto deben ser identidos por ejemplo si alguien vive en **Calle cedro** pero en uno pusieron **Cedro** y en otro **Calle Cedro** no coincidiran lo mismo con la ciudad ya sea por acentos, espacios, error ortográfica... y muchas variables más.

> EDITADO

Tenia

```
INNER JOIN TRABAJA TRB ON TRB.id_empresa=EMP.id_empresa
```

lo correcto es

```
INNER JOIN TRABAJA TRB ON TRB.id_empleado=EMP.id
```

debio marcarte error

En caso que siga mostrandote más de una vez el mismo empleado; fijate que cada empleado este asignado a un solo jefe y en una sola empresa; de otra forma puede ocasionar varias veces repetido, agrega los IDs de empleado, jefe y empresa, si se muestra más de una vez misma combinación deberás revisar mas a fondo la consulta a fin de eliminar aquello que lo repite, pero si no se repite misma combinación de IDs entonces el resultado es correcto.

Comment: Hola Roberto, gracias por tu respuesta. Tengo un problema utilizando tu código, en este caso, un empleado se repite 4 veces, es decir, supongamos que "Juan" vive en la misma calle y ciudad que su jefe, este aparece 4 veces en el resultado del query. Alguna idea de el por qué?. Estoy un poco confundido realmente.

Comment: Hola Roberto, ha sido perfecto!. Sí me salió el error que indicaste pero, supe seguido la razón y lo solucioné, aunque me salía un empleado repetido como te comentaba anteriormente. Con el cambio que le has hecho se arregló, muchas gracias. Aún sigo sin entender cómo funciona el INNER JOIN en detalle pero, ahí vamos, poco a poco.

Comment: hola, a mi este link me ayuda mucho para estos temas: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/